# install ros hydro ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ros-hydro, ubuntu, ubuntu-trusty

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm probably missing something obvious here so a push in the right direction would be a great help. I've a new computer, some of the hardware was not supported until Ubuntu Trusty, hence I've been stuck in windoze land for a month and a half. Now I've got Trusty installed, everything works great, but when I try to install ROS, no joy. It would appear that I'm stuck in the no mans land in between releases. Hydro installation instructions only go up to 13.10, Indigo won't be available until May.

Is it just a matter of adding the 12.04 sources to my sources list?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/155631/install-ros-hydro-ubuntu-14.04/) by [richkappler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2694/richkappler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2014-04-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [richkappler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2694/richkappler/) on 2014-04-21**:
ADDITIONAL INFO: Tried doing the install using 12.04 sources, got the following:

sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ros-hydro-desktop : Depends: ros-hydro-common-tutorials but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-hydro-geometry-tutorials but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-hydro-robot but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-hydro-ros-full but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-hydro-ros-tutorials but it is not going to be inst

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are some alpha releases of Indigo that you should be able to install on 14.04.

All of the dependencies for the big variants such as desktop-full aren't released yet, so you'll have to install individual packages. The current list of packages that are released for Indigo is: http://www.ros.org/debbuild/indigo.html

Adding the 12.04 sources to your machine probably won't work, because ROS depends on specific versions of system libraries such as Boost, and the versions of those libraries that are available on 12.04 and 14.04 are different enough to make installing the 12.04 binaries on 14.04 very difficult.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-09-17**:
i dont get this answer, the question was about how to install ROS hydro on 14.04. Where can I find the alpha releases for HYDRO on 14.04?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-09-17**:
ROS *Hydro* is officially only supported on 12.04. No Debian packages are and will be available for 14.04. You can try to build it from source on 14.04 though - but you should be confident in your ability to handle any upcoming issues. The official ROS distro for 14.04 is *Indigo*.